# Results of updating a vector in clojure

Tags: clojure, apache-spark, flambo

I have a function in developed in clojure using flambo spark api functions

```
(:require [flambo.api :as f]
          [clojure.string :as s])

(defn get-distinct-column-val
 "input = {:col val}"
 [ xctx input ]
 (let [{:keys [ col ]} input
       column-values []
       result (f/map (:rdd xctx) (f/fn [row]
                                   (if (s/blank? (get row col))
                                       nil
                                       (assoc column-values (get row col)))))]
   (println "Col values: " column-values)
   (distinct column-values)))
```

And I try to print out the values of column-values and I'm getting

```
 Col values:  []
```

Is there any reason as to why this is so?

I tried replacing the println in the above function with this:

```
(println "Result: " result)
```

and got the following:

```
 #<JavaRDD MapPartitionsRDD[16] at map at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just a small comment : assoc requires 3 or more arguments, you are passing only 2. See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc . @noisesmith provides good answer I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your code alters the `column-values` binding. I'm not sure how flambo works in the specifics here, but you should be looking at `result`, not `column-values`.

`assoc` takes two arguments - an associative collection and a position. I suspect that here you actually want `conj`. Neither `assoc` or `conj` alters the collection it is provided - we are using immutable data types here.

I expect that accessing `result` won't yet have the answer you expect, because you expect `assoc` to build up a value across each call (differently from the result from `f/map`). In this case, you probably want `reduce`.

Comment: Thank you so much @noisesmith: I actually thought the `assoc` function will help in building up the data structure in for the `column-values`, and quite frankly I Implemented a function and noticed that although I use `assoc` to update a map, when I try to print to result I still get the original set of data (i.e before the update using `assoc`) doesn't seem to reflect.. I'm lost on what to do

Comment: Look up the docs for `reduce`, it's meant for building up values from a collection.

Comment: So I decided to do a full audit of all the codes I've developed thus far, so that I don't end up with code that doesn't work

Comment: I have a function that transforms a sample dataset by splitting each line on tab: `(defn split-on-tab-transformation [xctx input ]
  (assoc xctx :rdd (-> (:rdd xctx)(spark/map (spark/fn [row] (s/split row #"\t"))))))`  in another function  assuming the above function will works I did this `...(-> (:rdd xctx) (f/map (f/fn [row] (get row 4)))...` and surprisingly I got `[\0 \0 \0]` . I wanted it to get the fourth element in the vector but for some reason Its returning the fourth character in the first element in the vector. Can you help me with this?

Comment: can you help me with the above problem in the above post? A sample row of the dataset is `[2.00000 770127      200939.000000    6094 BENTONVILLE, AR DPS 22.500000 5.000000 2.500000 5.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1 Store Tab 0.000000 4.50 3.83 5.00 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 19.150000]
` I'm new to clojure and I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Ps: the `spark/map` and `f/map` works the same way as the clojure map - @noisesmith